# File size exceeds the configuration limit - PyCharm

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I know this error is suppose to be resolved by configuring the `idea.properties` file and that's exactly what I have done yet this error still occurs.

I've set the `idea.max.content.load.filesize` in `idea.properties` to `2500000` yet I'm still facing this error. Anybody know why?

Error
`The file size (47.96 MB) exceeds the configured limit (2.59 MB). Code insight features are not available`

Comment: What type of file are you trying to load? Python files shouldn't be this large

Comment: Note: `2500000` bytes is `2.5 MB`, as the error says, so unclear why you expected that to work for `47.96 MB` file

Comment: @OneCricketeer a .yml file

Comment: Well, take your largest file, and calculate the _bytes_, and update the value, accordingly.

Comment: @OneCricketeer changed it to ```50000000``` yet still same issue which is 50mb. Should I increase it even more?

Comment: Now what does `exceeds the configured limit` say the size is?

Comment: @OneCricketeer 2.56 MB

Comment: Set also `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` property value

Comment: The values are in kilobytes, by the way, so if it's not changing, then you're editing the wrong value https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov do i set it to the same value as ```idea.max.content.load.filesize```

Answer (score 3):

Try following [this article](https://ayekpleclemence.medium.com/pycharm-ide-file-size-exceeds-configured-limit-2-5m-8640847d0099)

Important part is editing idea.max.intellisense.filesize key.

Comment: At the very top of the screen. Go to "Help" -> "Edit Custom Properties..." and edit/add (without quotes) "idea.max.intellisense.filesize="

Then "Quit" Pycharm and relaunch Pycharm